# How to get line thickness less than 1 with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have been trying to draw a thin horizontal line with PDFBox, but it appears that there is a limit for how thin I can draw the line. If I use a value less than one for the line thickness it looks the same as when I provide one for the value. Is this a limitation with PDFBox, or do I need to do something different?

```
// This looks the same as providing 1 for setLineWidth()
contentStream.setLineWidth(0.5f);
contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
contentStream.moveTo(40f, 30f);
contentStream.lineTo(570f, 30f);
contentStream.closeAndStroke();
```

Comment: Is your `contentStream` an instance of `PDPageContentStream`?

Comment: From the spec: "The actual line width achieved can differ from the requested width by as much as 2 device pixels, depending on the positions of lines with respect to the pixel grid." `SetLineWidth` just passed the parameter to the content stream... you can also have a look at the content stream with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Yes, it is an instance of PDPageContentStream

Answer (score 1):

A simple stroke call worked for me.

```
contentStream.setLineWidth(0.5f);
contentStream.moveTo(40f, 30f);
contentStream.lineTo(570f, 30f);
contentStream.stroke();
```

Comment: That isn't really different from the code from the question. It would only look different depending on line ending settings, but the question was about the thickness.